# ASPNET Core img src wildcards for image extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, kestrel-http-server

I've uploaded images in `wwwroot` of my project with their name matching name of the product (stored in database). Now I want to show them on my view but don't know their extension as user'll be able to upload any type of image file. Are thier any **wildcards** or any **other techniques** to resolve this? My code is:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="~/Uploads/Images/@(item.ProductName)/@(item.ProductName).png" alt="@(item.ProductName+" - "+item.ProductDescription)" />
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName)
      </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductPrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityOnHand)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: you cannot do much more than @esiprogrammer suggestion.
Anyway, consider a different approach: when user upload the image, store in the database the information you will need later to download the file: (including the file name and extension for download)
I usually have a table "uploads" where I keep an unique id, and the complete file name. After that, you need to store the id of uploaded file in the product table, and chose the best way to store the files (all files in the same folder, one folder for product or even store files in a db blob)

Comment: thank you @GianPaolo will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best way to do that, but alternatively you can GetAll files (which in your case supposed to be only one file) and than find the extension

```
 var imagesDirectory = Server.MapPath("/Uploads/Images/" + item.ProductName);
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(imagesDirectory,"*"+item.ProductName+"*");

 var extension = Path.GetExtension(files[0]);
```

Comment: bro can't use `Server.MapPath` it's Deprecated. Secondly, I'll be using many types of files in the project (.doc,.docx,.xlsx,.xls) in with case it'll become cumbersome to retrieve files like this. Thank you.